# How Referrer-Policy header can secure a website?

Tags: header, referrer, referrer-policy

I'm trying to get my website as secure as possible. I'm reading about headers and I should add a Referrer-Policy. However, I'm not sure to understand how this header can make my website more secure.

To be honest, I'm not sure to know how it works. I think the browser get as referrer the previous link.

My website use HTTP not yet HTTPS and I don't know which referrers should I use. I think the default is Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade, but my website use HTTP so that's useless.

Answer (score 2):

its been a while utile you ask but your best answer is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Examples)

and according to [this](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/) blog its how Referrer-Policy works :

> When
>   a user clicks a link on one site, the origin, that takes them to
>   another site, the destination, the destination site receives
>   information about the origin the user came from. This is how we get
>   metrics like those provided by Google Analytics on where our traffic
>   came from. I know that 4,000 users came from Twitter this week because
>   when they visit my site they set the referer[sic] header in their
>   request.

in simple word, it's about users privacy!